# Index out of range for an array

Tags: python, arrays

```
size = len(home)
total_score = []
score = []

for counter in range(0, size):
    print("Enter the Scores for", name[counter],":")

    score[0].append = int(input("Judge 1: "))
    score[0] = validate(0,10,score[0])

    score[1] = int(input("Judge 2: "))
    score[1] = validate(0,10,score[1])
```

when I run the above code i get the following error and I have tried everything to correct it.

```
score[0].append = int(input("Judge 1: "))
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You haven't provided enough code for us to reproduce this (if we run this code we will get `NameError` because `name` isn't defined. Additionally, you should post the full traceback for the error you get so we know where the IndexError is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

You initialise `score` to an empty list. Then on the first iteration of your loop you try and do something with the first element. However, the list is empty so it will produce an index error.

Note, [`.append`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm) appends an element to the end of the list. You need to do this operation on the whole list, not on an element of that list.

```
score.append(int(input("Judge 1: ")))
```

Answer (score 2):

As @DavidG mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49192992/7831383), you are trying to access the first element of an empty list by doing:

```
score = []
// [...]
score[0] // anything with this
```

---

But even when correcting this, you should consider the following:

You are iterating through `name` (as you use `name[counter]` in your loop).
However, for some reason, you are basing `counter`'s range on `len(home)`.

What if `home` has more elements than `name`?

---

Also, is there any reason why those two blocks don't share the same *logic*?

```
score[0].append = int(input("Judge 1: "))
// here ^^^^^^^
score[0] = validate(0,10,score[0])

score[1] = int(input("Judge 2: "))
//      ^-- nothing there
score[1] = validate(0,10,score[1])
```

should be (for example):

```
score.append(validate(0,10,int(input("Judge 1: "))))

score.append(validate(0,10,int(input("Judge 2: "))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem @DavidG is correct. `.append` is only used to add elements to the end of a list. The correct code to add an element to the list would be `score.append(int(input("Judge 1"))`.

For what you are trying to do, try creating your list like this:

```
score = [None] * 2
```

Then use the code in @Rafalon 's answer. That way, `score[0]` and `score[1]` won't trigger index out of range errors.